# Anchor tag not working with Angular UI-Router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I want to pass a parameter through anchor tags in the following `$stateProvider` code of AngularJS, but it is not working. What is the proper way to send a parameter via anchor link in `ui-sref`

```
<a ui-sref="Type/valid">Valid Email</a>
<a ui-sref="Type/invalid">Invalid Email</a>

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('Type/valid');
    $stateProvider.state("Type", {
        url:"/Type/:type",
        templateUrl: "valid.php"    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ui-sref` you can specify arguments like that

```
<a ui-sref="Type({ type: 'valid' })">Valid Email</a>
<a ui-sref="Type({ type: 'invalid' })">Invalid Email</a>
```